# How do I publish SQL Server Database to Azure to update existing database

Tags: sql-server, azure, deployment

I publish my SQL Server database on my local machine to Azure via Management Studio.

Say I name the database on Azure "California". The first time I do it its ok.

Then I made changes on my database on local, adding columns, adding data, etc. Then I want to deploy this database to Azure again.

But now Management Studio won't let me do it. It says database "California" already exists on Azure.

I can get away with this problem by deleting existing "California" on Azure first, then deploy again. But this seems not correct...Every time I make database changes on local, I need to delete the one on Azure before I deploy?

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to create a database project in Visual Studio to maintain your database schema and then you can do a database compare to create a script to update the database on Azure.

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2013/01/28/using-visual-studio-database-projects-in-real-life.aspx

RedGate Schema Compare will also do a similar thing.

Comment: Thank you. I read the blog. Looks like what I need to do is syncing local database to the database project, then syncing the database project to Azure database. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Basically all schema changes you make should be done in the database project you can then sync any databases you need. I use it all the time and it works well.

Comment: Hello there, good sir. I did as the blog says but when I compare my database project to my Azure database, it keeps saying that there are no differences detected. Are there any other configurations that I'm missing? I left the options on default.

Comment: Maybe there are no differences.

Comment: I use Visual Studio to update Azure databases but would like to see a CI build that did it automatically when I checked in the database project

Comment: I recommend using DBUP if you are using a .Net solution. Issue is if your database is massive then creating scripts to create it from the ground up is going to be tedious and no one will want to do that. Its something you want to ideally start using when you create your database.

It creates your DB and applies updates when your app compiles. Also creates a SchemaVersion table to keep track of this.

Answer (score 2):

**Update Jan 2020**

(I'm assuming the question is to update the schema on Azure, not update data)

If you are using Code First for creating your database. Then it is really simple.

Assuming your connection string is pointing to a local database (the one you want to update to Azure)

1. Make the changes to your entities
2. Create a new migration for those changed (Add-Migration etc)
3. Update the migrations to your local database.
4. Now just change the connection string to point to your Azure database
5. Update the migrations again, which will now update to the Azure database

Voila! That simple

Answer (score 1):

I know its been a while since the question was asked, however, there is no accepted answer. Thus to aid anyone coming here with a similar issue the following link describes a number of methods.

I prefer deploying a SqlDb from SQL Management Studio

`http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-deploy/`

> How to: Deploy to SQL Database
>   In Management Studio, connect to an on-premises SQL Server instance that has a database you want to migrate.
>
> 1) Right-click the database --> Tasks and click Deploy Database to SQL Azure.
>
> 2) In Deployment Settings, enter a name for the database.
>
> 3) Click Connect.
>
> 4) In Server name, enter the 10-character server name, followed by .database.windows.net.
>
> 5) In Authentication, choose SQL Server Authentication.
>
> 6) Enter the administrator login name and password that you provisioned when creating the SQL Database logical server.
>
> 7) Click Options.
>
> 8) In Connection Properties, in Connect to database, type master.
>
> 9) Click Connect. This step concludes the connection specification and takes you back to the wizard.
>
> 10) Click Next and click Finish to run the wizard.

Comment: I used exactly this method. But as I describe in the original post, this can only be done for the first time. Afterwards, if you change local database and want to deploy again, Management Studio report error: `The database 'xxx' already exists on the target instance of SQL Server. Specify a database name that does not already exist.`

Comment: Although i didn't add it - i tried deploying to Azure three times with the aforementioned methods (Sql Man studio) and every time it would rewrite the database with the new publish -> it didn't warn of a database already existing (fyi - i did use the exact same name)

Comment: OP wants to deploy to an *existing* database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL 2012, you can export a data tier application (bacpac) file, then import that when you login to your SQL Azure instance.

Comment: does that include data? or just schema?

Comment: That includes data. 

For Schema only changes,
If you are using codefirst (EF)  then you can just package up scripts. or run the migration directly against your db. 

Add-Migration (will create a migration based on whats in your db context to whatever is in you connection string) Start by enabling migrations by typing in Enable-Migrations in the packet manager console.

Then Update-Migration will execute the migration on that db.

if you want to script out the changes use 
Update-Migration -script and it will give you the sql you need to run.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue, but finally found [Microsoft data migration assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) which allows you to migrate schema and data from a source database to target database (existing).

Tested migrating schema and data from my on-prem SQL server to Azure SQL Database and it worked out very well (just needed to uncheck migrating Users).

It seems to be actively maintained as well, as the last published version was in Q4 2023.