# Publish dacpac to SQL Azure without recreate

Tags: sql-server, azure, deployment

I'm trying to perform a very simple task but cannot figure out how to do this with MS softwares.

I have a dacpac file extracted from a local SQL Server Express 2014.
I have to overwrite a remote database on SQL Azure cloud V12 with this file.

In SQL Management Studio it only allows to create a new Azure database from a dacpac file, but not to overwrite an existing one like I used to do with normal SQL Server 2014 database (publish data-tiers).

In Visual Studio, there is the publish to data-tier option on the Azure SQL database but it fails with the error : "A project which specifies SQL Server 2014 as the target platform cannot be published to Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12". Well how to I publish to Azure then ? I obviously cannot have a local Azure database on my computer.

I know I can delete the target database and recreate it from a dacpac but it takes a while ! Because I'm going to perform this operation frequently, this is not a solution for me.

**So, how do I publish a dacpac to overwrite a SQL Azure database V12 without deleting the database first ?**

Note: This question is not a duplicate of the link below. I already tried schema compare in Visual Studio but this is way too slow, unpredictable, and requires too much handwork to correct comparison errors. [How do I publish SQL Server Database to Azure to update existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531619/how-do-i-publish-sql-server-database-to-azure-to-update-existing-database?rq=1)

Comment: Are you using TFS Online Release Pipeline to deploy your solution to Azure?

Comment: @Elferone No I don't think so. Thanks but I've abandoned using SQL Azure, it didn't fit my needs.